# Gradient Stop Locations at Variable Values SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, user-interface, variables, swiftui, gradient

I'm trying to make a gradient composed of 4 stops in SwiftUI. I'd like the middle two to be anchored to the bottom of a specific stack. Something like this:

[Imgur Link of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q79cS.jpg)

Here's the gradient code I currently have:

```
LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [

//top       Gradient.Stop(color: Color(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 0.0, opacity: 0.0), location: 0.0), 

//variable1 Gradient.Stop(color: Color(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 0.0, opacity: 0.3), location: 0.30 //<-Variable), 

//variable2 Gradient.Stop(color: Color(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 0.0, opacity: 1.0), location: 0.35 //<-Variable), 

//bottom    Gradient.Stop(color: Color(hue: 0.1, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0.0, opacity: 1.0), location: 1.0)), 

startPoint: UnitPoint.top, endPoint: UnitPoint.bottom)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the frame size of the "Content Box" to determine at what position to place the gradient stop. I did this by just having a variable called frameHeight.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    var frameHeight = 200
    var body: some View {
        
        let gradient = Gradient(stops: [Gradient.Stop(color: .blue, location: 0.0), 
         Gradient.Stop(color: .white, location: CGFloat(frameHeight)/screenHeight), 
         Gradient.Stop(color: .black, location: CGFloat(frameHeight)/screenHeight + 0.05), 
         Gradient.Stop(color: .black, location: 1.0)])
        VStack{
            
            //Content Box view of frameHeight
            VStack {
                Text("Content Box")
                
            }.frame(width: screenWidth, height: CGFloat(frameHeight))
           
            Spacer()
        }.frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: UnitPoint.top, endPoint: UnitPoint.bottom))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```